# Removing unique validation list from Work sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to generate a validation list.  As a test I put "myList" in cell A5.  It will not always be in a fixed location.  I want to generate a Macro that will remove all validation lists which are "mylist".  I can't remove all validation lists (`cells.validation.delete`) as other lists are present in the worksheet.  Any support would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Ciaran.

```
    Sub List_Test()

Dim myList$, i%

myList = ""

For i = 1 To 7

    myList = myList & "ListItem" & i & ","

Next i

myList = Mid(myList, 1, Len(myList) - 1)

With Range("A5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add _
    Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=myList
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So, `myList` could be something like `1ListItem1,`? and you're grabbing `ListItem1` from there, then want to find that data validation and remove it?  For your list, why not create a range array or something?

Comment: Thanks for your input - I really appreciate all input received.  mylist is a "Listitem".  When I setup a range and step through it looking for a cell that is a xlValidatelist and formula1:=mylist - VBA doesn't like the ":" in Formula1:.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. I can't reproduce the error.  Try removing the `_` and put the `.Add` all on one line: `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList`

Comment: That worked - very odd.  Thank you very much for your support..!!!  Can you please put it in as an answer so I can give you credit.  Thanks again.  Ciaran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your (maybe all?) VBA doesn't like the multiple lines, just put the `.Add` on one line:

```
Sub List_Test()

Dim myList$, i%

myList = ""

For i = 1 To 7

    myList = myList & "ListItem" & i & ","

Next i

myList = Mid(myList, 1, Len(myList) - 1)

With Range("A5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @user1624926 - You're welcome. The thing is though, *why* wasn't it working for you? I tried it how you have it, and it ran for me without errors...Hm, weird.